# Send arguments from JQuery to Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

I'm trying to send the data from an input (text field) on my index page back to flask for processing and return the processed data to the index page.

I can display the value that is inputted via an alert in javascript, but as soon as i try send it to flask it does not show.

Here is the code I am trying to use.

**script.js**

so when the submit button is clicked, it sends a POST command to the flask app with whatever is currently in the text field (shown in index.html). It waits for a response and outputs it to the "#reply" div

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  $.post("/serviceidlookup", {serviceid1: document.getElementById("field")}).done(function (reply) {
    $('#reply').empty().append(reply);
});
```

**flaskapp.py**

The first part of this sets up the index page with the text input and submit button. The second part is the function that is called by the previous JQuery script and is passed an argument. it renders the lookup.html page and returns it to the JQuery script (which then inputs it to the "#right" div)

```
@app.route('/')
def index(name=None):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)

@app.route('/<serviceid>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def serviceidlookup(serviceid):
    serviceid2 = serviceid + " extra"
    return render_template('lookup.html', serviceid=serviceid, serviceid2=serviceid2)
```

**lookup.html**

This takes the values passed to it by the "serviceidlookup" function as previously described

```
{% if serviceid %}
<h1>Hello {{ serviceid }}!</h1>
<h1>And also {{ serviceid2 }}!</h1>
{% else %}
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
{% endif %}
```

**index.html**

This contains the test field and button that is used to send the information off. it also contains the "#right" div that is filled in by the JQuery

```
<div id="searchContainer">
<input id="field" name="field" type="text" />
<div id="delete"><span id="x">x</span></div>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
</div>

<div id="reply">
</div>
```

It must be something i'm doing wrong with sending the arguments to flask, can anyone spot a problem?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think your Javascript is not even being triggered - you have a syntax error in your script.js (you can view syntax errors in the javascript console if you are using Google Chrome).

I have re-written your application as follows to get it working as expected:

**flaskapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug=True

@app.route('/')
def index(name=None):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)

@app.route('/serviceidlookup', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def serviceidlookup():
    serviceid = request.form.get('serviceid')
    serviceid2 = serviceid + " extra"
    return render_template('lookup.html', serviceid=serviceid, serviceid2=serviceid2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**static/script.js**

```
  $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
           var serviceid = document.getElementById("field").value;
           $.post(
              "/serviceidlookup",
              { serviceid: serviceid }
           ).done(function (reply) {
              $('#reply').empty().append(reply);
           });
        });
  });
```